# Is initializer_list considered part of the C++ core language?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, initializer-list

I ask because `auto` deduces`{}` to be `initializer_list`. I don't know of any other class in the standard library that the core language depends on like this. You could take out `vector` or `array` and C++ would still function, but take out `initializer_list` and it would break.

Comment: Vector, array. Initializer list, etc. are all part of the C++ STL. They are classes.

Comment: @ChrisMM The core language needs intializer_list, so is not also part of the core langauge?

Comment: @ChrisMM If by STL you mean the C++ standard library, then yes. But seeing as the question specifically asks about it being part of the core language I don't see how it being a standard library type has anything to do with anything.

Comment: There are more overlaps between the core language and the library types, like sizeof(x) returns std::size_t, typeof(x) returns std::type_info, and dynamic_cast might throw a std::bad_cast. Not to mention "library" functions like is_constant_evaluated().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you call `{}` (specifically `= {...}`) the standard calls *copy-list-initialization*.

And yes, `std::initializer_list` is [given special consideration in the wording of the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.auto.deduct#3).

> If the *placeholder-type-specifier* is of the form *type-constraint* `auto`, the deduced type `T` replacing T is determined using the rules for template argument deduction. If the initialization is **copy-list-initialization, a declaration of `std​::​initializer_­list` shall precede ([basic.lookup.general]) the *placeholder-type-specifier*.**

```
[Example 1:
auto x1 = { 1, 2 };             // decltype(x1) is std​::​initializer_­list<int>
auto x2 = { 1, 2.0 };           // error: cannot deduce element type
auto x3{ 1, 2 };                // error: not a single element
auto x4 = { 3 };                // decltype(x4) is std​::​initializer_­list<int>
auto x5{ 3 };                   // decltype(x5) is int
```

Comment: May want to mention that a raw `{...}` is a [*braced-init-list*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.general#nt:braced-init-list)

Comment: It behaves like a built-in type, yet is part of library. Worse than that no rvalue support, nor constexperable(due to absence of methods implementation). The worst hack to C++ type system ever